# Derivative at a point (Linear approximation at point)--what is the valid range for approximation?

Tags: calculus

Derivative at a point $x=c$ for $f(x)$ gives linear approximation (approaching a tangent) at that point.

But what is the range around $x=c$ for this approximation is valid? What books say is only $\lim_{\Delta\to 0}$?

Assume $f(x)$ = $x^2$. At $x=3$, I have derivative($f(x)$ = $2x$ of 6 which is actually a limit.
From right of x=3 i,e ${x \to 3^+}$,we should have   ${\Delta x\to 0}$ .

Example 1 for  ${\Delta x\to 0}$ is 0.3,0.2,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.00001..........

Example 2 for  ${\Delta x\to 0}$ is 0.4,0.3,0.2,0.0,0.01,0.001,0.00001..........

I am looking for maximum first term that is allowed.

Comment: If you want a more precise answer than "[it depends](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/291594/856)" you'll have to be more precise about what you mean by "valid".

Comment: Assuming I understand the question correctly, there need not be a range of validity. For example $f(x)=x^2$. The derivative is, of course, $f'(x)=2x$, which gives the slope of a tangent line at a point, but if you take any two distinct points, no matter how close, you will not find this value to be the slope.

Comment: @clayton -- sure you will, as long as the two points are on either side of the point of interest. Central differences.

Comment: @bubba: My intention was for it to be the slope at a point. If you consider points other than the one you're interested in, then yes, of course it's possible. If one point is fixed, and you want to have a valid range such that the slope between the fixed point and any other point corresponds to the derivative, then there is no valid interval, that is why we take the limit.

Comment: @Clayton: Thanks for points made. very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation can only be deemed good if you specify what good is. A quick demonstration: "A good approximation to $\pi$ is that it is roughly $7654.88$" is a statement that is as true as "A good approximation to $\pi$ is that it is roughly $3.14159265$". Both have no meaning before you specify 'good for what'. It will be correct to say that "$3.14159265$ is a better approximation (or at least not worse) to $\pi$ then $7654.88$ is, regardless of what you want the approximation for".

Your question can be made precise and has many interesting and important answers. You will surely get to see Taylor approximations to functions and then you will learn about various forms for the remainder. I believe that will answer your question fully as you will see there conditions that assure that you can actually say something sensible about the linear approximation (and higher order approximations) of a given function. However, for a general differentiable function with no other knowledge other than differentiability there is nothing that can be said about the quality of the approximation. A famous function is Cauchy's function $f(x)e^{1/x^2}$ whose Taylor approximation is constantly $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the second paragraph. Its road ahead for me.